# Diminutive forms - usage

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, diminutives

Reading from  some grammar sources, I came to know that *bullet* is a **diminutive** of *ball*.

Nevertheless, as far as I know, *bullet* is nowadays mostly used in the sense of "gun-bullet".

So can *bullet* really be considered a coherent/ standard diminutive of *ball*, so that the former can be used to describe small- sized round objects eg:- chocolate *bullets*?

Comment: butt and buttocks are different terms. Not all words have diminutive form even if there are a lot of doggies around. And bullet is most definitely not a diminutive of bullet.

Comment: See the wikipedia article about bullet 
that says bullet is diminutive of ball https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet#:~:text=10%20External%20links-,Description,which%20means%20%22small%20ball%22.

Comment: That's French, not English. ***The term bullet is from Early French, originating as the diminutive of the word boulle (boullet), which means "small ball"***.

Comment: Origin of ball is also french ( balle)

Comment: Similar example :- home ( ham) > hamlet (french). Ham is french for home town. The same word is retained in english too eg:- nottingham. Here, ham obviously means "home"

Comment: Conclusion? Ball is not a diminutive form of bullet. Please capitalize country adjectives. And ham is most definitely not French for home town. The original French term is: hamel and hamelet, which mean a little village.

Comment: Well.. hamel is still a  diminutive form of ham according to chamber's etimological dictionary. see https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/08/hamlet.html

Comment: Chambers notes that hamel itself was a diminutive of ham, a word for home in many old Germanic languages, including ***Old English***.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on 'bullet'  has: 'The term _bullet_ is from Early French, originating as the diminutive of the word _boulle_ (_boullet_) which implies that the ex-French loanword was already a diminutive when it appeared in English: an Early French diminutive. [Etymon](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bullet) concurs: **bullet**: 1550s, "cannonball" (a sense now obsolete), from French boulette "cannonball, small ball," diminutive of boule "a ball" (13c.),

Comment: *bullet is nowadays only used in the sense of "gun-bullet"* No, one of its most common uses is in typography ("bullet points").

Answer (score 1):

Historically, *bullet* comes from Middle French *boulette*, and that is a diminutive of their *boule*. But *ball* comes from Middle English, not from any version of French (though ultimately they all trace back to the same Proto-Indo-European origin). So no, *bullet* is a cousin of *ball*, not a diminutive.

Now, as to whether it can be used in the way you suggest, feel free to do so. But I doubt you’ll have any company.

Comment: The sense of *ball* that we do get from the French is the dance.

Comment: Should, by definition, diminutive  and augmentative forms  be of same origin to be recognized  as such?

Comment: It's possible that OP was thinking of something like ["Mozartkugeln"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozartkugel) (as "Kugel" can have both meanings in German). That doesn't apply to any candies in English as far as I'm aware, though.

Comment: Not only will he not have company, I doubt anyone will understand him. But someone has to be the first to try out a new word or usage, maybe they'll be lucky and it will catch on.

Comment: [Only in 'Murica.](https://www.chocolateammo.com/chocolate-bullet-chocolate-ammo-military-style-tin)